# ssh with pubkey

Tags: ssh

I have a fresh ubuntu 20.04 cloud server and fail to access the machine with ssh using public/private key authentication

here is my configuration

- the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** on the remote has the following options

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AllowUsers [username]
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
x11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

- the `/home/[username]./ssh/autorized_keys` file on the remote has a copy of my public key
- the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on my local machine has an entry for the remote server (created when PasswordAuthentication was still allowd

still I am getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` when I try to `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa [username]@135.181.xx.yy`

Can anyone point me to the error I am obviously making? I seem unable to find the similar examples. Actually the setting are identical to another 18.04 server where they are working fine.

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my post. it is ~/.ssh/id_rsa. I shut the server down and started it again, and now it works. I wasn't aware that restarting the sshd service would not be sufficient.

Comment: Usually restarting the server's sshd service *is* sufficient. I've never needed to reboot the server,

Comment: There are several possibilities - misspelled `ssh/autorized_keys` file; wrong (too permissive) file permissions; encrypted home directory that prevents reading of the file prior to login/decryption; ... Try running the ssh command with extra verbosity using `-v`/`-vv`/`-vvv` and look for anything suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good sofar. I've got a similar setup:

On my server there is the `authorized_keys`file, the known_hosts file is locally.

I created the file: `~/.ssh/config`with the following content:

```
Host mycloud
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With this combination I can login like this:

`ssh username@mycloud`

If you don't have that config file on your host you need to login like this: (it will copy your public key)

`ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub username@mycloud`

That will not work out of the box if your server is in the cloud. I had to change the following on my server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config:`

```
PasswordAuthentication no

Match User anotherUser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
```

That means that there is "anotherUser" that still may login with a password. For all other users the public/private file authentication is activated