# How can I give a non-root user SSH access

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, login

I purchased a Digital Ocean Droplet and enabled SSH authentication rather than password authentication. I was able to configure the root SSH key correctly and can login on my laptop under the root user, but I had a tough time enabling SSH key access for a newly created user. I went into the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and added `AllowUsers root mynewuser`, but this didn't let me login with `ssh mynewuser@ipaddress`.

I was finally able to get it working with these commands taken from a DO fourm:

````
mkdir /home/mynewuser/.ssh
chmod 0700 /home/mynewuser/.ssh/
cp -Rfv /root/.ssh /home/mynewuser/
chown -Rfv mynewuser.mynewuser /home/mynewuser/.ssh
chown -R mynewuser:mynewuser /home/mynewuser/
gpasswd -a mynewuser sudo
echo "mynewuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | (EDITOR="tee -a" visudo)
service ssh restart
usermod -s /bin/bash mynewuser```
````

This seems like a lot of work to do every time I want to simply give someone the ability to login with their SSH key, and it also doesn't let users have unique SSH keys, instead, they have to use the SSH key created during the server setup (the same one root uses). Is there an easier way to give SSH access to non-root users, and if so, is there also a way to give them a unique key?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Don't do the NOPASSWD part. That is inherently insecure. Why not doing it [this way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290463/906933)?

Comment: Does "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" gives your "non-root" mynewuser full root access without using any password? If you give any "non-root" user the private key for the root in the remote VM, then they can use `ssh root@IP_Address_of_Your_Digital_Ocean_Droplet` and login as root. Both these things (a)giving the private root key; and (b) allowing NOPASSWORD ALL, are security risks.